# How to change the cipher suites list in Chrome & Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

In Firefox, it is clear how to edit the cipher suites list simply from about:config. From digging in the web, I know that it is quite complicated in Chrome and IE. Some references show how to black list some ciphers in Chrome but I am looking for how to find the list of the supported cipher suites by Chrome? then, how to disable and enable some? 
Similarly, I need to know the same for IE?

Can you please help me with more step by step explanation?

Comment: [IE11](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/changing-ies-ssl-cipher-order.355446/)and [Chrome](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4)

Comment: @Ramhound the 2nd link is from iana. It does not mention Chrome in any way. Can you clarify?

Comment: **Google linked to that, in reference to cipher suites and chrome, chrome supports all of those.**

Comment: @Ramhound I do not think so. This is too long list & can't be the default one. If the default list is greater than 256 Byte, this is not good may cause server to choke.

Comment: Why do you think the list is "too long"?

Comment: @Ramhound I found a general and more reliable way. See the solution. The iana's list if too long because it is a list of all possible cipher suites that ca  be used in tls protocol. Normally, the list that the browsers configured with (the default list) are much less (in firefox case, I found 32 ciphers only).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to know the list of cipher suite that any browser (client) send by using sniffing tool such as wireshark. I opened an ssl page, then from `edit` -> `find` searched for the string `client hello` then inside this packet, I could find the list of cipher suites which is the exact list the client sent.

Answer (score 0):

This is now rather an old question, but...

For [MSIE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/steriley/2007/11/07/changing-the-ssl-cipher-order-in-internet-explorer-7-on-windows-vista/), this is configured via Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> SSL Configuration Settings. Note that the policy is "disabled" by default, meaning that the system is choosing the ciphersuite depending on some hard-wired configuration. When you enable the policy, the preference list is populated with all the available cipher suites *in alphabetic order!*

I am still struggling to find out how to do this for Chrome, but if you point your browser at https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/ you will see what it thinks the preference is. Note that the names it reports are *like* the OpenSSL names (rather than the IANA names used by MSIE) but not an exact match - they omit the curve algos for EC.